# Why is JSON_UNESCAPED_LINE_TERMINATORS not unescaping my newlines?

Tags: php, json

Based on the [documentation](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php), I'd expect `JSON_UNESCAPED_LINE_TERMINATORS` to preserve newline (`\n`) characters unescaped, so as actual newlines, when encoding JSON:

> `JSON_UNESCAPED_LINE_TERMINATORS` (integer)
> The line terminators are kept unescaped when `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` is supplied. It uses the same behaviour as it was before PHP 7.1 without this constant. Available as of PHP 7.1.0.

Minimal example:

```
$ php -r 'echo json_encode(["foo" => "bar\nbaz"], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_LINE_TERMINATORS) . "\n";'
{"foo":"bar\nbaz"}
```

I expected:

```
{"foo":"bar
baz"}
```

<s>(Note that this is valid JSON; only `\` and `"` *must* be escaped in a string.)</s>

Why doesn't this option work as expected?

Answer (score 9):

**[Edit] I was reading the JSON spec incorrectly: unencoded newlines inside a string are *not* valid JSON. Control characters from U+0000 through U+001F *must* be escaped. PHP is correct not to include them unencoded, although the documentation can clearly be improved!**

I had to go to the [source](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/da0663a337b608a4b0008672b494e3a71e6e4cfc/ext/json/json_encoder.c#L340) to find this out. A "line terminator" in this context only refers to the obscure Unicode code points U+2028 LINE SEPARATOR and U+2029 PARAGRAPH SEPARATOR:

```php
                /* Escape U+2028/U+2029 line terminators, UNLESS both
                   JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE and
                   JSON_UNESCAPED_LINE_TERMINATORS were provided */
                } else if ((options & PHP_JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)
                    && ((options & PHP_JSON_UNESCAPED_LINE_TERMINATORS)
                        || us < 0x2028 || us > 0x2029)) {
```

This is in conflict with what Unicode [defines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Unicode) as a line terminator:

> The Unicode standard defines a number of characters that conforming applications should recognize as line terminators:
>
> ```
> LF:    Line Feed, U+000A
> VT:    Vertical Tab, U+000B
> FF:    Form Feed, U+000C
> CR:    Carriage Return, U+000D
> CR+LF: CR (U+000D) followed by LF (U+000A)
> NEL:   Next Line, U+0085
> LS:    Line Separator, U+2028
> PS:    Paragraph Separator, U+2029
> ```

Answer (score 2):

This is the result of a few conflicting specs.

- Javascript does not allow unescaped line-endings within strings.
- JSON is supposed to be a subset of javascript.
- *Therefore,* JSON also does not allow line-endings within strings.

However, JSON and javascript had different definitions of what constituted a “line ending”, with JSON being more lenient. JSON allowed U+2028 and U+2029, but javascript did not. (I’m speaking in the past tense here, because ES5 updated javascript’s spec to allow them.)

In the meantime, PHP tries to keep you safe. For example, by default, it escapes the `/`, even though it does not need to be escaped per the spec, just in case you’re embedding JSON within HTML and might include the text `</script>` within your JSON, which would break the HTML. So by default, PHP makes that `<\/script>`. You can turn this off with `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES`, but there’s not really any need to do so unless you really want to shave bytes in your payload. Any JSON parser will treat `/` and `\/` as identical.

By default, PHP also escapes all non-ASCII. There's a bit more reason to turn this off, to make your JSON more human-readable and also to save significantly more bytes, and you can do so with `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`. Now, however, you have the potential for those pesky line endings to appear in your data, which *may* break some parsers. (Specifically, they’ll break javascript `eval()` pre-ES5, which you probably shouldn’t be using to parse JSON anyway, but some people do.) Again, PHP tries to keep you safe, using the same logic as it does to escape the forward slash even though that’s technically unnecessary. So these two characters are encoded by default. There’s almost no need to turn this off*, but if you do want to, `JSON_UNESCAPED_LINE_TERMINATORS` gives you the option.

If you’re not using `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`, all non-ASCII characters are escaped anyway, so `JSON_UNESCAPED_LINE_TERMINATORS` has no effect.

---

* These are rare characters, so they’re probably not in your string to start with. If they are present, they’ll be present only once or twice, so escaping them will not cause a great deal of bloat.

---

Note: The comparison with `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` is not my own: it was brought up in [the Github discussion proposing this change in PHP](https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/1701).