# How to allow json_encode() accept \n as a new line?

Tags: php, json, newline

I am encoding my array to JSON format but it is not breaking line from the new line operator (\n).

So how to achieve this

```
$array = ["string" => "hello \ngood morning!!"];

$encodedJson = json_encode($array);
dd(encodedJson);
```

Outputs

```
{"string":"hello \ngood morning!!"}
```

But what I wanted is

```
{
  "string" :"hello
   good morning!!"
}
```

I also tried

`json_encode($array,JSON_UNESCAPED_LINE_TERMINATORS);`

Comment: _"but what i wanted is `{"string" :"hellogood morning!!"}`"_ - what, so you want the newline to completely disappear? That doesn't seem to match what you were asking for in the question title.

Comment: yes i updated my code sorry my bad

Comment: A line-break in JSON is always encoded as `\n`. When you decode it, you'll see there's a linebreak there. Does this answer your question? [Are multi-line strings allowed in JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392766/are-multi-line-strings-allowed-in-json)

Comment: why you want the carriage return in the json string? what the advantage instead of \n?

Comment: What you are asking for makes no sense to begin with, because that would be _invalid_ JSON. You can not have actual line breaks in JavaScript text literals delimited with double or single quotes.

Comment: This appears to still be directly related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/71732900/1427878, so you should have continued the discussion there, rather than ask a new question.

Comment: @CBroe: I think the new question was much better than the old one. Much more succinct. Perhaps it is better to delete the old question.

Comment: No, if you want valid JSON. Please search and find any number of existing questions and answers on this, e.g. [Why is JSON_UNESCAPED_LINE_TERMINATORS not unescaping my newlines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64238947/why-is-json-unescaped-line-terminators-not-unescaping-my-newlines).

Comment: The best you could do as far as valid JSON is: `{   "string" : [  "hello",  "good morning!!" ] }`, and then pretty-print that, ie. split your string into an array. And then `join` when you output. If you must have the line-breaks that is.

Comment: i checked this question but i thought it was not helping me

Comment: The question/answer above also notes, **unencoded newlines inside a string are not valid JSON**. Also the earlier question I linked has an answer with reference to JSON spec and notes, **Newlines are "control characters" so, no, you may not have a literal newline within your string.**, and also **JSON does not allow "real" newlines in its data; it can only have escaped newlines.**. Knowing that "it's not possible" should be helpful, don't chase for tricks that evade specification. If you need a particular display that's not supported "raw", find an IDE that provides it.

Comment: so what i am looking is irrelevant and illogical according to you i guess?

Answer (score 6):

What you want is not valid JSON.

The JSON data format does not support literal new lines in the middle of strings.

There is no way to make `json_encode` produce that output (and if you could, you then couldn't parse the result in any standard JSON parser).